# Is there a way to intercept Undertow RequestTooBigException in spring-ws

Tags: spring, spring-boot, soap, spring-ws, undertow

I have spring boot application that provides some rest api and soap interface using spring-ws.

I'm restricting all post requests to less than 50MB using 
`server.undertow.max-http-post-size=50MB.`

The restriction works but not the error handling.

Tried using a SoapFaultMappingExceptionResolver and mapping RequestTooBigException as an exception inside that. That didn't work because I think this is blocked by undertow and that's before the soapExceptionResolver is triggered.

Tried using a @ExceptionHandler but same result.

Since it's a soap request the accepted type is not json and the default spring exception handler tries to return json with the details of the exception, thus resulting in the following in the logs:

```
2019-09-17 09:24:11.715  WARN 12564 --- [XNIO-1 task-23] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation]
 2019-09-17 09:24:11.950 ERROR 12564 --- [XNIO-1 task-75] io.undertow.servlet.request              : UT015012: Failed to generate error page /error for original exception: io.undertow.server.RequestTooBigException: UT000020: Connection terminated as request was larger than 52428800. Generating error page resulted in a 406.
```

Is there a way to either intercept that exception for the WS services, or to make the spring default error handler to return the exception as XML (just for the ws)?

Answer (score 0):

> Tried using a @ExceptionHandler but same result.

I suppose that Spring considers that exception as a implementation detail of Undertow during the request processing that it performs and as a consequence it doesn't want to allow it leak above.

In Spring, you have exception handing and exception resolving.
Exception handlers are not always well designed to define a custom exceptions handling whether Spring implementation resolves them for you and apply a specific processing for.   There you look like in this case.

But all is not lost. A clean and possible approach (not tested) is to implement your own exception resolver to prevent Spring to map that Undertow exception into a `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException`.
Since you use spring-ws, you should implement `org.springframework.ws.server.EndpointExceptionResolver` or more simply `AbstractEndpointExceptionResolver` or `SimpleSoapExceptionResolver`.
Implement `resolveExceptionInternal()` to perform the logic in case of that exception is thrown :

```
public class MyEndpointExceptionResolver extends AbstractEndpointExceptionResolver {

    public MyEndpointExceptionResolver(){
       setOrder(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected abstract boolean resolveExceptionInternal(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint, Exception ex){
      if (ex instanceof RequestTooBigException){
         // create the response message with the exception
         WebServiceMessage message = ...
         // set it in the MessageContext
         messageContext.setResponse(message);
         return true; // resolved
       }
      return false; // leave the default resolver doing its job
    }
}
```

Note that you may have multiple active exception revolvers for a same layer/concern. So you have to set the precedence of this one over the default one.
`setOrder(0)` does that.